# Masonry method: "appended" forces reload on Wordpress Page

Tags: php, wordpress, infinite-scroll, masonry

I am on my way trying to get Masonry running with InfinitScroll. I found out that I need the appended method in Masonry. Example:

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/nhekz

This doesn't work properly because everytime I hit the append button, my Wordpress page reloads. The console says:

```
Updating because HTML element modified
```

After the reload all my added DIVs are gone.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was a html Element  which forces a page reload.

```
<h1>Masonry - appended</h1>
<p><button id="append-button">Append new items</button>
<div class="masonry">
  <div class="item w3"></div>
  <div class="item h2"></div>
  <div class="item h4"></div>
</div>
```

I used a div element insted of the button to add masonry elements and the problem was solved

```
<div id='test2'>click</div>
```